# Overriding a method generates an error stating it's not overriden even though the signature is the same along with parameters

Tags: c++, overriding, abstract-class

I have issues with an error message saying: ***pure virtual function :IObject::toString has no overrider***

I've seen multiple threads on it and the problem was that people didn't have the same signatures with parameters and thus never really "overriden" it but rather they did overloading. But in this example, I have the same signature and parameters (none) yet it still says the same error.

Here is abstract class **IObject.h**

```cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef I_OBJECT_H

#define I_OBJECT_H
#include<string>

class IObject
{
public:
    virtual std::string toString() const = 0;
};

#endif // !I_OBJECT_H
```

`toString()` method is pure virtual and needs to be overriden.

This is **IComparable** that is descendant of **IObject.h**

```cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef I_COMPARABLE_H
#define I_COMPARABLE_H

#include "IObject.h"
class IComparable :
    public IObject
{
public:
    virtual int compareTo(IComparable* obj) const = 0;
};


#endif // !I_COMPARABLE_H
```

And here I have the **Time.h** that overrides both functions `compareTo(IComparable* obj)` from **IComparable.h** and `toString()` from **IObject.h**

```cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef TIME_H
#define TIME_H

#include "IComparable.h"

struct Time : public IComparable {
public:
    Time(int aHours, int aMinutes, int aSeconds);
    virtual int compareTo(IComparable* obj) const override;
    virtual std::string toString() const override; // <-- overriden
private:
    int _hours;
    int _minutes;
    int _seconds;

    // custom operators for comparing
    bool operator==(const Time& obj) const;
    bool operator<(const Time& obj) const;
    bool operator>(const Time& obj) const;
};


#endif // !TIME_H
```

The error shows up in the main here (commented in the code)

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include "Time.h"
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    IComparable* array = new IComparable[ARRAY_SIZE]; // right before the first brace
// rest of the code...
```

Any idea why do I get this error even though i DID override it?

Comment: `IComparable` is an abstract class. You cannot create objects of its type in `new IComparable[ARRAY_SIZE]`. `IComparable` seems to be used as interface class. Why would you want to create objects of its type? Did you mean to write `new Time[ARRAY_SIZE]` instead?

Comment: @uneven_mark oh you are right, I completely missed that part, thank you!